# Meteor and Color Thief won' work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have been using meteor to create a little project that show a list of music album. Now the music album data is stored in template helper like this:

```
    var albumsData = [
      {
        artist:'artist name',
        title: 'title album',
        url: 'http://...',
        review: 'Lore ipsum',
        sauce:'lostyears.png'
      }, ...
];
Template.albumsList.helpers({
  albums: albumsData
});
```

and the part of the template relative to it is:

```
 <div class="album-info">
    <div class="unit size3of5">
        <h6>{{artist}}</h6>
        <h2 id="primaryColor">{{title}}</h2>
        <a href="{{url}}" class="secondaryColor">Listen on...</a>
        <p>{{review}}</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="unit size2of5">
       <div class="album-Image">
         <img id="myImg" src="{{sauce}}">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note how I dont need to specify the direction of the image becuase meteor automatelly find all the images inside the /public folder inside the project.

In the html template right after the htlm piece shown before I have been using color thief in this way:

```
<script>
  $(window).ready(function(){
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = colorThief.getColor('{{sauce}}');
    document.getElementById("primaryColor").style.color = "rgb(" + color + ")";
   });
</script>
```

The list of album show up properly color thief doesn't seem to work no matter what I do, which may me think if there is something about Meteor I am not aware of. Also want to make notice that the Color-Thief.j and Quantize.js are included in the client folder.

Thank you guys

EDIT: Since meteor handle logic and template in separate files I create a new template helper in this way:

```
    Template.albumItem.helpers({

  color: function() {
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    return colorThief.getColor(this.sauce);
  }

});
```

Where color is used inside the template albumItem in this way:

```
<h2 style="color:{{ color }}">{{title}}</h2>
```

Still not working but I am sure this was a move to the right direction, maybe now we need to figured out how to know that this template start after the image is load...

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `var color = colorThief.getColor('{{sauce}}');` with `var color = colorThief.getColor($('#myImg'));`

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but still not working, now I am gonna try the method suggested by Kaoskeya

Comment: what does `console.log(color);` send back?

Comment: It say that color is not defined! So it's like it didn't create that variable at all

Comment: oh my bad, I made a mistake in my code. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the following code.

```
{{#each albums}}
    {{> ImageBanner}}
{{/each}}
```

Image Banner template is (please edit it to suit your design):

```
<template name="ImageBanner">
    <img src="/{{ sauce }}" />
    <h5 style="color: {{ getColor }}">Yo</h5>
</template>
```

The Javascript parts.

```
Template.ImageBanner.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;
    instance.color = new ReactiveVar("#000000");
});
Template.ImageBanner.helpers({
    getColor: function() {
        var instance = Template.instance();
        function componentToHex(c) {
            var hex = c.toString(16);
            return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
        }
        function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
            return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
        }
        var ct = new ColorThief();
        instance.myImage = new Image;

        instance.myImage.onload = function() {
            var rgb = ct.getColor( instance.myImage );
            instance.color.set( rgbToHex( rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2] ) );
        }
        instance.myImage.src = this.sauce;
        return Template.instance().color.get();
    },
});
```

Comment: I tried this and is not working. Plus now the data from the albumsData is not showing anymore. I guess the reason that doesn't work is because the image need to lead first in order to estract the color

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure the image needs to load too, unsure where albumsData isn't showing.. I'll have a look at this tomo morning and update if is still not sorted..